# Is there a way to force formatters to use English if the device's language is not supported?

Tags: swift, localization, nsformatter

We make heavy use of formatters in the app for numbers and date/time. And we found out that the app doesn't look nice when the device's language is Arabic for example, which is a language we don't support. See this screenshot for example for a device with Arabic set as the device's language (no other languages added to device's preferences):

[image]

The localised free trial period is shown in Arabic. The numbers at the bottom as well. And all dates/times in the app show in Arabic as well.

English is set as the development language, but that doesn't seem to be enough. And I read [How iOS Determines the Language For Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014938) and my understanding is that English should've been the language used as it is set as the development language.

Do formatters/localisation methods not follow the same rules as well?

Is there a way to force formatters/localisation methods to use English if the device's language is not supported by the app?

**Edit:**
Just switched the device's language to Japanese and Russian and the same view showed completely in English, as desired, so not sure what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify the `Locale` of a formatter:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also force English for non-English languages supported by the app? Also please see the edit, this issue didn't show with Japanese & Russian.

Comment: Yes, however you can check if their current language is not supported and assign the locale to the formatter